# Getting an error regarding input shape when calling predict function for a LSTM model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have fitted a lstm model. There are 100 observations for each x and y variables. I used 80 values to train the model and 20 values to evaluate the model.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout

input_features=1
time_stamp=100
out_features=1
x_input=np.random.random((time_stamp,input_features))
y_input=np.random.random((time_stamp,out_features))

train_x=x_input[0:80,:]
test_x=x_input[80:,:]

train_y=y_input[0:80,:]
test_y=y_input[80:,:]
```

Then I reshaped the data as it necessary to do so before feeding the data into LSTM function.(Ex: For training x:(samples, timesteps, features)=(1,80,1))

```
dataXtrain = train_x.reshape(1,80, 1)
dataXtest = test_x.reshape(1,20,1)
dataYtrain = train_y.reshape(1,80,1)
dataYtest = test_y.reshape(1,20,1)
dataXtrain.shape
(1, 80, 1)
```

Then I was able to fit the model successfully using following lines of code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20,activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True,input_shape=(dataXtrain.shape[1], 
dataXtrain.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(dataXtrain, dataYtrain, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=1)
```

But when I predict the model for the test data, I am getting this error.

```
y_pred = model.predict(dataXtest)
Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have shape (80, 1) but got array with shape (20, 1)
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what is the problem here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is with data preparation. I think you should divide your **samples** (instead of time-steps) to train and test data and the shape of train and test samples should be the same and like `(None, time-steps, features)`.

Since you have just one sample with 100 observations (time-steps) you can divide your data into samples containing small size time-step series. For example:

```
n_samples = 20
input_features = 1
time_stamp = 100
out_features = 1
x_input = np.random.random((1, time_stamp, input_features))
y_input = np.random.random((1, time_stamp, out_features))

new_time_stamp = time_stamp//n_samples
x_input = x_input.reshape(n_samples, new_time_stamp, input_features)
y_input = y_input.reshape(n_samples, new_time_stamp, out_features)

dataXtrain = x_input[:16,...]
dataXtest = x_input[16:,...]

dataYtrain = y_input[:16,...]
dataYtest = y_input[16:,...]
```

Alternatively, you can collect more data samples each containing 100 time steps (it depends on your application and your existing data).

Also you can look at [this](https://stackabuse.com/solving-sequence-problems-with-lstm-in-keras/) and [this](https://stackabuse.com/solving-sequence-problems-with-lstm-in-keras-part-2/) that explained using LSTM in Keras comprehensively.